# Why does jquery recognizes an element stored as a string in a variable when using .prop(), but not when using .text()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I stored an Id of a  in a variable,`variantId = $(this).prop('id')` and noticed 2 different behaviors of Jquery:
When I changed the `prop` of the `<td>` - jquery recognized the element stored in the variable **although it was stored as a string**,

```
let variantId;
$(document).on('click', ".tbl-itemClass", function () {
    variantId = $(this).prop('id');
    $(variantId).prop('contenteditable', true);//changed the prop

}).
```

but when I tried getting the value of the `<span>` nested in the `<td>`, using `.text()`, jquery only recognized the element stored in the variable when `'#'` was added

```
    on('input', function () {
            let newItemName = $('#' + variantId).find('span.item-description').text();
            //let newItemName = $(variantId).find('span.item-description').text(); //this line returned an empty string instead of the <span>s value.
        })
```

**this is the full code:**

```
let variantId;
        $(document).on('click', ".tbl-itemClass", function () {
            variantId = $(this).prop('id');
            $(variantId).prop('contenteditable', true);

        }).
            on('input', function () {
                let newItemName = $('#' + variantId).find('span.item-description').text();
                //let newItemName = $(variantId).find('span.item-description').text();
            });
```

**This is my .csHtml** (don't think it makes a difference, I'm using razor page, Asp.Net)

```
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr currentitemid=" @item.Id">
        <td class="tbl-itemClass desc" id="@("description"+ item.Id)" varianttype="@ViewBag.VariantType" >
            <span class="spnSpc">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
            <span style="width:90%; padding:1px 5px 1px 2px;" **class="item-description"** contenteditable> @item.Description </span>
        </td>
        
        <td class="tbl-itemClass ">//more code here
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Can you explain the **difference** please? Thanks!

Comment: The issue is because the `id` value is just whats contained in the quotes in the HTML, eg `id="foo"` => `foo`. To select the element using a CSS/jQuery/sizzle selector you need to prefix the id with `#`, so the parser knows exactly what you're trying to do -> `#foo`. I'd suggest doing some research on CSS selectors if this is new to you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: and by the way I wonder how `$(variantId)` worked because it's inconsistent ... if variantId is a string it will be evaluated as a css selector and the id alone won't select anything. While when you do `$(this)`, that's an HTMLElement that gets wrapped in a jQuery object so that you can use the jQuery methods on the element

Comment: Please insert a runnable snippet in your question (use the toolbar) that includes the (minimal) HTML to reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: Try to log the `variantId` before doing `$(variantId)`, I guess that it will become clearer why. 
I suspect it contained a tag name, so jquery still found something.

Comment: How are you *setting* the `id` `prop`? What value does it have in each place? As trincot says, please add a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is that this line

```
    $(variantId).prop('contenteditable', true);//changed the prop
```

did NOT work,
and the reason why you can mistaken and think it works is because it has the `contenteditable` attribute in the html element.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, if you want to select attribute by ID you need to put:

```
$('#yourId')...
```

As you are getting variantId stored and used as id, to access elements .text() you need # as id selector.

Comment: The Asker is asking why apparently it works without "#" in the first case.